# How to connect to an SQLite(CE) database on a windows mobile phone?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-mobile

I want to make a database for my mobile 6 cellphone app. What I did was in visual studios I went to my project name and right clicked on it, went to add -> add new item -> data -> choose datafile.

It created a database file called "AppDatabase1.sdf"

Now I want to connect to my database but I don't know how what the connection string is since I see no app.config where I normally would expect it to be.

So I just have

```
 SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Not sure what to put here");
 conn.Open();
```

When I click on the server explorer tab I see my database so I click on it. In the properties section it has something labeled "connection string" however it looks like the path to the actual file and when I run it in the emulator I get an error.

> "The database file cannot be found.
>   Check the path to the database."

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create the database outside your application. It is probably better if you had a fail-safe so that if the user accidentally deletes it or it does not exist, then you can re-create it easily. This is good for initial installations. The following code will do what you want (SQLCE/Mobile 2005 example):

```
Private Sub ConnectToDB()
        If (File.Exists("\SystemCF\LPI\inventory.sdf")) Then
            Try
                cn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=\SystemCF\LPI\inventory.sdf;Password=")
                cn.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try

        ElseIf (File.Exists("\UserCF\LPI\inventory.sdf")) Then
            Try
                cn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=\UserCF\LPI\inventory.sdf;Password=")
                cn.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try

        Else
    Try
       If (Not (Directory.Exists("\SystemCF\LPI"))) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory("\SystemCF\LPI")
       End If

       Dim engine As New SqlCeEngine("Data Source=\SystemCF\LPI\inventory.sdf")
       engine.CreateDatabase()

       cn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=\SystemCF\LPI\inventory.sdf")
       cn.Open()

       Call dropAndCreateDatabase()
     Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
       MessageBox.Show("Unable to create database!", "Database Create Failed")
     End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source =" + filename + ";password=" + password;
connection.Open();
```

Of course, the `password=<password>` part is required only if you protected the DB, which is not the case by default.

BTW, this isn't SQLite, it's SQLServer CE (or *SQLCE* for short).

EDIT: If you only specify the file's name (no path), make sure that the file is in the current **working** directory. Obviously, according to the error message, there's something wrong with the way you specify the filename. My bet is on the path, just specify it and you should step forward.

EDIT2: In order to check if the problem is in your program or in the DB file, [download DataPort Console](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html) and use it to open your DB in the device. That wayn you can validate that your DB can be accessed correctly.

Comment: ah. We searching for the answer I saw SqLite too and thought it might be another name for it. Anyways I don't think I have a password and I did  this SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = AppDatabase1.sdf"); but I still get the database cannot connect.

Comment: Is there a special folder? Mine is in the root directory of my project.

Comment: I don't know I can't get it to work. Is it possible for you to make a sample program. I tried the direct path to the actual database, I tried what you had above. The only way I can get it to work is if I use like a dataset control but I can't find the connection string it makes so I could use it.

Comment: Just to check it works: Copy your .sdf file in the root of your device, then use "\filename.sdf" in the connection string. It should work. Also, I added some advice in my answer to test that the DB can be opened using another program.